# How remember the whole function result?

Tags: python

I want to create an intelligent DiscFree indicator.

Code:

```
import os
os.system("df -h")
```

I want to use regular expression (to cut the size in MB), but I can't, because the function returns disk space and value "0".

```
result = os.system("df -h")
```

Variable "result" is "0".

How can I access to disk space and use it?

Comment: Use `subprocess`, in particular [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: The `0` you are seeing is the return code of the successfull `df -h` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for invoking console commands:

```
import subprocess

def command(cmd):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds = True)
        stdout = p.communicate()
        return stdout[0]
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception(ex)

df = command("df -h")

print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   233Gi  160Gi   72Gi    69% 42083619 18985821   69%   /
devfs          187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%      648        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%        0        0  100%   /home
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) instead of os.system

```
import os
result = os.popen("df -h").read()
print result
```

**Note:** os.popen is deprecated as of Python 2.6 and [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is available since python 2.4 so if you want code to work on Python >= 2.6 use `subprocess` and if support for Python < 2.4 is important use `os.popen`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can consider using some library functions to get the free space:

```
import os
s = os.statvfs('/')
print (s.f_bavail * s.f_frsize) / 1024**2
```